# Full elastic collision in two dimensions with equal mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, kinematics, momentum, collision

I am currently dealing with a physics problem. It is stated that a pool billard ball collides with another. I guess it's a fully elastic one, it's not mentioned. Furthermore, it's stated that, after the collision, Ball A travels at 1.3 m/s in a 45 degree angle relative to the edge, and Ball B parallel to the edge with 1.5 m/s. Both have equal mass, namely 170g. The kinetic energy and total momentum needs to be calculated.

My problem with that question is the following: If both pool balls have the same mass, then the two impulse vectors should form a right angle, so we can access this problem as pythagorean;

[image]

So we could use the following equations:

[image]

[image]

But, in the question it is stated that Ball A is at a 45 degree angle to the edge, and Ball B at 0 degrees (exactly parrallel), so the angle between them is also only 45 degrees. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram with the right angle assumes that ball 2 was at rest before the collision. If the angle is not a right angle, this means ball 2 was not at rest initially. Both balls were moving. If you can find a reference frame where the angle is 90 deg after the collision (rather than 45 deg), ball 2 should be at rest in this reference frame before the collision.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. You're right, because I just assumed that the ball 2 was at rest, which obviously is not the case as they don't form a right triangle. It's not stated in the assignment either

Comment: @冰淇淋 In any case, the total momentum and kinetic energy is easily calculated from the figures given for the velocities after the collision. You don't really need to bother about the collision at all for this.

Comment: yeah I just need to use the cosine function for the black ball as it's movement is 2-D, and 1.3 m/s is the x component, so the 1.3/cos45 should give the velocity, and then I can calculate the momentum and kin. energy, and for the white ball it's all 1-D and easy to calculate